# Как реализовать запрос на ввод данных в связующую таблицу?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Например есть 3 таблицы, `USER`, `WORK`, и связующая `user_work`. Связующая содержит `id` основных таблиц. Я вот не могу понять, как их в ней объединить? Как должен выглядеть запрос на вставку данных в основные таблицы и в связующую? Если можно пример кода с реализацией php.

Comment: @Michael74, любопытно: одна работа может быть назначена нескольким пользователям? Если да, то создавайте по очереди пользователя, работу, затем связь. Т.е. у пользователя программы будет 3 разных страницы, например.

Comment: так весь смысл в том, что данные в эти таблицы вставляются в разное время. Когда вы хотите добавить связь user и work у вас уже есть оба id.  
Ну или если вас редактирование, скажем, идет на одной странице и добавляются и user и work и user_work, то делайте это последовательно. вставили user, получили id, вставили work, получили id, вставили в user_work оба id.

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL

Пусть для определенности структура таблиц `USER`, `WORK` и `user_work` будет определяться следующими тремя таблицами

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE WORK (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_work (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  work_id int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

Обычно заполняют сначала таблицы `USER` и `WORK`, получая после каждого из INSERT-операторов идентификаторы только что вставленных записей. В MySQL для этого предназначена фукнция `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Если мы выполняем операцию заполнения в SQL, то нам придется сохранить их в переменные при помоищ оператора `SET`.

```
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(NULL, 'hello');
SET @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO WORK VALUES(NULL, 'world');
SET @work_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Получив внешние ключи для пользователя `@user_id` и вида работы `@work_id` мы можем сформировать запрос на вставку записи в связующую таблицу `user_work`

```
INSERT INTO user_work VALUES(NULL, @user_id, @work_id);
```

## PHP

При заполнении таблиц в PHP будем ориентироваться на расширение PDO

```
<?php
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'root',
    '',
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]);

  // Добавляем сообщение в таблицу USER
  $query = "INSERT INTO USER VALUES(NULL, :name)";
  $user = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $user->execute(['name' => 'hello']);

  // Получаем только что сгенерированный идентификатор id
  $user_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

  // Добавляем сообщение в таблицу WORK
  $query = "INSERT INTO WORK VALUES(NULL, :name)";
  $work = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $work->execute(['name' => 'world']);

  // Получаем только что сгенерированный идентификатор id
  $work_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

  // Вставляем содержимое новостного сообщения в таблицу user_work
  $query = "INSERT INTO user_work
            VALUES (NULL, :user_id, :work_id)";
  $relate = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $relate->execute(['user_id' => $user_id, 'work_id' => $work_id]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```